# socket.io private updates in specific rooms

Tags: socket.io

This question has been asked several times, but any of the answers is a solution to my problem.

issue:
There will be multiple accounts, and accounds will have multible users. In one specific account, the users will do some realtime updates - but the other accounts will be not affected from those real time changes, every accounts will be private.

We are planing to create room names for each account from cookie

Also we are using node in PHP project.

Sorry for my broken English!

```
// client side code

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
var msg = $("#messageInput").val();
socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );
// Ajax call for saving datas
$.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/insertMessage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
return false;
});
socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' +      data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;
$( "#messages" ).append( newMsgContent );
 });


//server side codes
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
console.log( "New client !" );

client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

    //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message }  );
  });
});

server.listen( 8080 );
```

Comment: What does "using node.js in a PHP project" mean?  If node.js is your web server, what is PHP doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create private chat rooms as below.

**Server side code**

```
// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['room1','room2','room3'];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room1');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        // leave the current room (stored in session)
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        // join new room, received as function parameter
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

**Client side code**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updaterooms', this updates the room the client is in
    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div>' + value + '</div>');
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></div>');
            }
        });
    });

    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>ROOMS</b>
    <div id="rooms"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

Reference Link:

http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/